# Cheapest way to cover garage ceiling

Tags: ceiling, garage

I'm looking for the cheapest way of covering my garage ceiling. The purpose is mainly to cover all the exposed insulation.

The measurements are 5.9 meters by 5.4 meters approximately.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The cheapest is to staple plastic over it.  Code(fire) might require drywall.

Comment: What is above the garage, and where on the planet are you?

Comment: @crip659, not just code, but common sense.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I live in New Zealand. Also I don't use the garage for parking. Just for working out and WFH

Comment: You may not intend to use it as a garage but the building codes may have some regulations. Drywall is certainly widely used in Australia and so I assume in NZ too. There is a new product available in the US called Trusscore(TM) which might be a good choice for DIY but of course might not be allowed in NZ. This appears to be absolutely 1st rate construction so presumably anything you would put up should be of that quality rating.

Comment: Are you planning to do it yourself, or pay someone to do it, or it depends on difficulty? Most materials are cheap, including drywall (the most "optimal" choice in terms of end results IMO) but its harder to install drywall than say a bunch of plywood.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend drywall. In my area, the least expensive 1/2" drywall is currently cheaper than the least expensive 1/2" (or close) plywood, but I am sure prices vary a bit depending on local production, local popularity of different products, shipping costs and other factors. Weight is similar in the 40 lb - 50 lb per 4'x8' sheet range, depending on exact thickness and type.

##### Drywall Advantages

- Easy to cut to fit odd-shaped areas
- Easy to cut later to run electric or other cables

##### Plywood Advantages

- Stronger, particularly if you want to hang things from the ceiling

In either case, you will need to move, and possibly rewire, any lighting or other electrical fixtures. It may make sense to install new lighting for the entire ceiling with appropriate cabling and junction boxes, but in a garage you can have exposed conduit on the surface of the ceiling connecting lighting fixtures, so there are plenty of options. But you can't just put the existing cables above the ceiling unless they are rated for that type of installation.

Comment: Either way, renting a panel lift makes this job MUCH easier than the old approach of two people and T-braces.

Answer (score 0):

Being a garage, in NZ, its not rated for living, so you can put up anything. If you are doing it by yourself then I would suggest lightest grade plywood.

You could leave it as is, or stain / varnish before you put it up.